# Does the Riemannian distance function obey the Leibniz rule?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, differential-geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold, and let $
\alpha,\beta:[0,\delta) \to M$ be two smooth paths satisfying $\alpha(t) \neq \beta(t)$ for every $t$.

Suppose that for every $t$ there is a unique length-minimizing geodesic from $\alpha(t)$ to $\beta(t)$. [This implies](https://mathoverflow.net/a/21316/46290) that the Riemannian distance function $d:M \times M \to \mathbb R$ is differentiable at the point $\left(
\alpha(t),\beta(t)\right)$.

Now, for a given (fixed) point $p \in M$, denote by $d_p:M \to \mathbb R$ the distance function from $p$, that is $d_p(q)=d(p,q)$. Its differential at a point $q \in M$ is denoted by $d(d_p)_q:T_qM \to \mathbb R$.

**Question:**
Does
$$\frac{d}{{dt}}d\left(\alpha(t),\beta(t)\right)=d(d_{\alpha(t)})_{\beta(t)}(\dot \beta(t))+d(d_{\beta(t)})_{\alpha(t)}(\dot \alpha(t))$$
hold?

This is a sort of "Leibniz-rule"...I tried to play with the formula described [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/21316/46290), using exponential maps and initial velocities of geodesics, but so far without success.

This Leibniz-rule clearly holds for the case of $\mathbb R^n$, endowed with the standard Euclidean metric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, this isn't related the Riemannian geometry at all. The result follows from the following general assertion:

> Let $f:M \times M \to \mathbb R$ be smooth. Then
> $$
> \frac{d}{{dt}}f\left(\alpha(t),\beta(t)\right)=d(f_{\alpha(t)}^L)_{\beta(t)}(\dot \beta(t))+d(f_{\beta(t)}^R)_{\alpha(t)}(\dot \alpha(t)),
> $$
> where $f_{p}^L$ and $f_{q}^R$ are the functions $M \to \mathbb R$ obtained by fixing the first and second variables to be $p,q$ respectively.

This is easily proved via observing the splitting of $T(M \times M)$ as a direct sum.